# Directly update mapbox source features

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm drawing orders on the map using layers with symbols, this orders has status. Whenever the status changes I'd like to change de color of the symbol.

My layer has this configuration:

```
map.addLayer({
    id: "orders",
    type: "symbol",
    source: "order-markers",
    layout: {
      "icon-image": [
        "match",
        ["get", "orderStatus"],
        "UNASSIGNED",
        "unassigned-marker",
        "ASSIGNED",
        "assigned-marker",
        "IN_TRANSIT",
        "intransit-marker",
        "CONCLUDED",
        "concluded-marker",
        "UNASSIGNED-marker",
      ],
    },
  });
});
```

Is there a recommended way to directly access the source and update the status in the properties object ? Or is it right to always overwrite the whole data object with setData ?

I tried to create a state in React with the features but it seems that the features object dont react to the state changes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a way to update a single property on a single feature.  What I've always done is to overwrite the data as you've mentioned (i.e.  `map.getSource('order-markers').setData(/*...*/)`) with the whole data object where a feature's property was changed.  This is the method mapbox uses in their example for updating with live data: [live-update-feature](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/live-update-feature/)

As an alternative however, you can update a single feature's state.  If that's a possibility you can use [map.setFeatureState](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#setfeaturestate).

for example:

```js
map.setFeatureState(
  {
    source: 'order-markers',
    id: feature.id,
  }, {
    status: "IN_TRANSIT"
  }
);
```

You'll then have to update your layer style/expressions to use the `state` instead of `property` to properly reflect the data as they are slightly different in how you get the values.

Comment: I liked the alternative but do you know if it is possible to set the feature-state during the creation of the feature? Because each order-marker can have a different status on the creation.

Comment: @Drealler Not that I know of, and I've tried instantiating them with state before, but it didn't work.  I've usually set it after creation with `map.setFeatureState` for each element.  Maybe someone else has better insight on this though.